How to calculate and display a range of precipitation values using raster calculator on a GeoTIFF file in QGIS
I am trying to use raster calculator to extract values from a GeoTIFF file showing rainfall. I would like to generate a raster with the range of 90-110 mm only see expression ("wc2.1_30s_bio_17@1"  >= 90 <= 110).
However, when I carry out the processing,  the new output raster only shows 0-1 values.

When an expression is True in raster calculator, 1 is returned, if it is False 0 is returned. So if you want the Trues to keep their values from your raster you should multiply by it.
I keep the values in the range 300 to 400, else I set them to 0.
(("nh_68_5@1">300) AND ("nh_68_5@1"<400)) * "nh_68_5@1" +
("nh_68_5@1"<=300)*0 + 
("nh_68_5@1">=400)*0

I've colored the zeros purple in styling:


Hi Bera - I appreciate your prompt response - thanks very much! Peter

What should I do when someone answers my question?
